# Change pointers value inside a function

Tags: php, laravel-excel

I'm using pointers `$break` & `$columns_match` to determine whether columns in Excel file cross matched with the table in db. The values of those variables change back to false each time a new chunk is processed. Even when I tried to make the variables private props of the whole class, it still changed back to false each time.

```
/** Init new variables **/
$break          = false;
$columns_match  = false;
$filename       = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();

/** Insert new log in upload_logs **/
$upload_log = Upload_log::create([
    *censored*
]);

/** Move uploaded file to imported files directory **/
$file = $request->file->move(public_path(*censored*));
$path = $file->getRealPath();

Excel::filter('chunk')->load($path)->chunk(1000, function($reader) use($tableName, &$columns_match, &$break) {

    var_dump('start:');
    var_dump($columns_match);

    if (!$break) {
        if (!$columns_match) {
            /** Truncate destination table before inserting data to prevent duplicates **/
            DB::connection(*censored*)
                ->table($tableName)
                ->truncate();

            /** Get destination table columns **/
            $columns = DB::connection(*censored*)
                ->getSchemaBuilder()
                ->getColumnListing($tableName);

            /** Check if destination table columns are found in uploaded file **/
            if ($reader->count()) {
                $headerRow = $reader->getHeading();
                $columns_match = !array_diff($columns, $headerRow);

                var_dump('change:');
                var_dump($columns_match);
            }
        }

        /** Check if uploaded file's headers match to destination table columns **/
        if ($columns_match) {
            /** Extract only the data we need in destination table from uploaded file **/
            $data = array_map(function($row) use($columns) {
                $arr = [];
                foreach ($columns as $column) {
                    $arr[$column] = $row[$column];
                }
                return $arr;
            }, $reader->toArray());

        /** Insert the data to destination table **/
            DB::connection(*censored*)
                ->table($tableName)
                ->insert($data);

                var_dump('end');
                var_dump($columns_match);
        } else {
            $break = true;
        }
    }
});
```

That prints:

```
string(6) "start:"
bool(false)
string(7) "change:"
bool(true)
string(3) "end"
bool(true)
string(6) "start:"
bool(false)
string(7) "change:"
bool(true)
string(3) "end"
bool(true)
string(6) "start:"
bool(false)
string(7) "change:"
bool(true)
string(3) "end"
bool(true)
```

Any thoughts of what is wrong?

Comment: This would happen if you didn't have `&` before the variables in `use()`. Are you sure you have that in the real code?

Comment: @Barmar Of course, that's a "copy & paste" of my code as it written in the file, no alterations (except the censored stuff obviously).

Comment: I can't think of anything else. Try echoing the variables inside the function to make sure they're being assigned.

Comment: I have updated the post to show the var_dumps. As you can see, at the end of each chunk the boolean still equals true but get resets to false at the start of a new chunk

Comment: Are you sure this is multiple chunks from the same loop, not multiple calls to this block of code? Can you reproduce it with a closure you just call in a loop yourself, instead of through Laravel Excel?

Comment: Definitely not multiple calls to this block of code since I have no other loops in it, only if statements.